# Issue with ImmutablePair after upgrading Apache Commons Lang3 version

Tags: kotlin, apache-commons-lang3

I am facing an issue with my code since upgrading the lang3 version from 2.12.0 to 2.12.13

`ImmutablePair(it, action).apply { className.invoke(this) }`

It was working fine before but after the update, it states

> "Not enough information to infer type variable T".

Is there any reason for this?

I turned it back to the old version since it broke the code

Answer (score 1):

1. I think your version numbers are wrong.  Commons Lang 3 version numbers start with 3.x see [Change Report](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/changes-report.html).
2. It would see from [this Java doc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html#apply-org.apache.commons.lang3.function.FailableBiFunction-), that a new method called `apply` was introduced in v3.13.0 to "Applies this key and value as arguments to the given function."
3. Because the underlying class now has an `apply()` method you cannot use Kotlin's `apply`. So the behaviour you see is not a Kotlin defect, but you are unwittingly using a totally different method from Apache Commons.
4. Remedy 1: You could use `run { }`, `let { }`, etc instead of `apply { }`
5. Remedy 2: Overall, what are you are you trying to achieve with `ImmutablePair` that cannot be achieve with Kotlin's native `Pair` class (which is immutable)? Consider changing to that!

You do not state what the object `className` is. Perhaps there is something else relevant with that.